# Probability random walk remains bounded

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a simple unbiased random walk on the discrete line starting at $0$. Fix a number $n$. As a function of $k$, what is the probability that the walk remains bounded in $\{-n,\ldots,n\}$ for the first $k$ steps? Alternatively, what is a good upper bound for this probability? I would like a stronger bound than $(1-2^{-{2n}})^k$.

Comment: Hi burtonpeterj and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: I asked this question on this site because I'm confident the answer is well known and I am not interested in recapitulating standard theory on my own.

Comment: Moreover, this question is much too basic to be asked on MathOverflow.

Comment: The generating function $E_0(s^T)$ where $T$ is the first hitting time of $\pm n$ can be computed explicitely. As a function of $s>0$, it diverges when $$s\to\frac1{\cos(\pi/(2n))}$$ A consequence is that, as a function of $k$, $P_0(T>k)$ decreases as $\cos(\pi/(2n))^k$, for example in the sense that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1k\log P_0(T>k)=\log\cos\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)$$

Comment: @Did: I think you should turn your comment into an answer and expand it. Thanks.